# Content of array in bash is OK when called directly, but lost when called from function

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops, ifs

I am trying to use xmllint to search an xml file and store the values I need into an array. Here is what I am doing:

```
#!/bin/sh

function getProfilePaths {
    unset profilePaths
    unset profilePathsArr
    profilePaths=$(echo 'cat //profiles/profile/@path' | xmllint --shell file.xml | grep '=' | grep -v ">" | cut -f 2 -d "=" | tr -d \")
    profilePathsArr+=( $(echo $profilePaths))
    return 0
}
```

In another function I have:

```
function useProfilePaths {
    getProfilePaths
    for i in ${profilePathsArr[@]}; do
    echo $i
    done
    return 0
}

useProfilePaths
```

The behavior of the function changes whether I do the commands manually on the command line VS calling them from different function as part of a wrapper script. When I can my function from a wrapper script, the items in the array are 1, compared to when I do it from the command line, it's 2:

```
$ echo ${#profilePathsArr[@]}
2
```

The content of profilePaths looks like this when echoed:

```
$ echo ${profilePaths}
/Profile/Path/1 /Profile/Path/2
```

I am not sure what the separator is for an xmllint call.

When I call my function from my wrapper script, the content of the first iteration of the for loop looks like this:

```
for i in ${profilePathsArr[@]}; do
    echo $i
done
```

the first echo looks like:

```
/Profile/Path/1
/Profile/Path/2
```

... and the second echo is empty.

Can anyone help me debug this issue? If I could find out what is the separator used by xmllint, maybe I could parse the items correctly in the array.

FYI, I have already tried the following approach, with the same result:

```
profilePaths=($(echo 'cat //profiles/profile/@path' | xmllint --shell file.xml | grep '=' | grep -v ">" | cut -f 2 -d "=" | tr -d \"))
```

Comment: What's wrong here? The loop does iterate over the two array elements. Please post a complete script that doesn't reference local files (so that we can run it on our machine), and explain clearly why the output is unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `--shell` switch and many pipes, you should use the proper `--xpath` switch.

But as far of I know, when you have multiple values, there's no simple way to split the different nodes.

So a solution is to iterate like this :

```
profilePaths=(
    $(
        for i in {1..100}; do
            xmllint --xpath "//profiles[$i]/profile/@path" file.xml || break
        done
    )
)
```

or use [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet):

```
profilePaths=( $(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//profiles/profile/@path" file.xml) )
```

it display output with newlines by default

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is related to data encapsulation; specifically, variables defined in a function are local, so you can't access them outside that function unless you define them otherwise.

Depending on the implementation of `sh` you're using, you may be able get around this by using `eval` on your variable definition or with a modifier like `global` for `mksh` and `declare -g` for `zsh` and `bash`. I know that `mksh`'s implementation definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing feedback on how I can resolve this problem. After investigating more, I was able to make this work by changing the way I was iterating the content of my 'profilePaths' variable to insert its values into the 'profilePathsArr' array:

```
# Retrieve the profile paths from file.xml and assign to 'profilePaths'
profilePaths=$(echo 'cat //profiles/profile/@path' | xmllint --shell file.xml | grep '=' | grep -v ">" | cut -f 2 -d "=" | tr -d \")

# Insert them into the array 'profilePathsArr'
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a profilePathsArr <<<"$profilePaths"
```

For some reason, with all the different function calls from my master script and calls to other scripts, it seemed like the separators were lost along the way. I am unable to find the root cause, but I know that by using "\n" as the IFS and a while loop, it worked like a charm.

If anybody wishes to add more comments on this, you are more than welcome.